# PHP json_encode returning single row only

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, session

So I have an associative array `$_SESSION['cart_items'])`  This is the current output when I `print_r($_SESSION['cart_items'])`:

```
Array
(
    [3] => 23
    [5] => 5
    [4] => 1
)
```

In the output above, the first one for example [3]=>23 where [3] is the id and 23 is the quantity I entered from a form:

My current data:

[image]

Note that in the image above, the quantity column is different from the quantity I'm entering from a form.

So far this is the code I've tried:

```
$statement = $conn->query("SELECT id, name, price, quantity FROM product WHERE id IN (".implode(',',$_SESSION['cart_items']).")");

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;

}

print json_encode($data);
```

And this is the output:

```
[{"id":"5","name":"ballpen","price":"23","quantity":"13"}]
```

As you can see it works, though I only get a single row which should be three.

Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Why should you get three rows?!? The sense of the json format is to convert complex data structures into a single string. There is no use for line breaks in that. So the question is: are you sure that you really want to `json_encode()` the output? _Why_?

Comment: @arkascha I mean I have 3 records in the database..

Comment: Ok, then I suggest you try that query manually. Most likely you will get only a single entry in the result set.

Comment: Are the product ids in DB `3,4,5` as are the _keys_ of `cart_items` or are the id `23,5,1` as are the values of the `cart_item` ? It's not clear from your example

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: And that's the answer : implode works on the values not on the keys...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You show that the array keys in the session array match the `id`s in the database.  `implode()` implodes/joins the values in the array. So you need to implode the keys:

```
implode(',', array_keys($_SESSION['cart_items']))
```

Or flip the array:

```
implode(',', array_flip($_SESSION['cart_items']))
```

Comment: So very fast. It works! How can I access the values also because Im using it in angular.

Comment: Depends.  `$ids = array_keys($_SESSION['cart_items']); $qty = $_SESSION['cart_items']`